# "Which dreams, indeed, are ambition" in Hamlet Act 2, Scene 2

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare, hamlet

I am reading *Hamlet*; Act 2 Scene 2 contains the following exchange:

> Hamlet: O God, I could be bounded in a nutshell and count myself a
> king of infinite space, were it not that I have bad dreams.
>
> Guildenstern: Which dreams, indeed, are ambition; for the very substance of the ambitious is merely the shadow of a dream.

What is the meaning of

> Which dreams, indeed, are ambition

What does the "which" refer to? The previous dreams? I understand it means "dreams are a sign of ambition". How does this follow grammatically?

Comment: Explain further if possible. What is a relative adjective?

Comment: so its: "those bad dreams, indeed, are ambition"

Comment: I’ve downvoted because it appears that the question is asking about basic English grammar.  It might be more suitable for the English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: Its only about grammar once you remove any ambiguity coming from Shakespeare's poetic intentions. It could be a raw grammar question, but it could be "what does Shakespeare mean here". So not best for a grammar page, particularly given it is not clear to the OP that this is just about grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific context, "which" is a [relative adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relative%20adjective) that refers back to the dreams Hamlet spoke of. Merriam-Webster gives the following example (emphasis mine):

> Our next meeting will be on Monday, **at which time** a new chairman will be elected.

Below is another example from [Linguapress](https://linguapress.com/grammar/relative-pronouns.htm#adjectives) (emphasis mine):

> He reached the village, **at which point** he stopped for a drink.

So it is as if Guildenstern completes Hamlet's last sentence: "I have bad dreams, which dreams, indeed, are ambition; (...)". Just a moment earlier, Rosencrantz had said that it was Hamlet's "ambition" that made him regard Denmark as a prison.

Note that "ambition" did not necessarily have the positive connotations that the word has today, as can be seen from the examples at [Why is Macbeth's “vaulting ambition” so important and famous?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16165/2191).

Comment: The thing is, both these examples use the more common "at which time" or "at which point". That has a totally clear meaning. If I said "our meeting will be next Monday, which time a new chairman will be elected", I think it would become confusing and unclear, particularly if the second part of the sentence was said by someone else, and it was referring to a dream. Perhaps it is fine to omit the "at"?

Answer (score 3):

Here is Merriam-Webster on this use of **which**

> used as a function word to introduce a nonrestrictive relative clause and to modify a noun in that clause and to refer together with that noun to a word or word group in a preceding clause or to an entire preceding clause or sentence or longer unit of discourse

[*In German, **which** language might … have been the medium of transmission.*]

— Thomas Pyles